# Condition for eigenvalues to have negative real parts (Hurwitz) for specific matrix structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, control-theory, hurwitz-matrices

Let

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix} P & \alpha x\\ -y^\top & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is Hurwitz (the eigenvalues of $P$ have strictly negative real parts), $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\alpha$ is a real positive scalar. Find the condition for $A$ to be Hurwitz for sufficiently small $\alpha > 0$.

---

I have analyzed that this is true whenever $y^\top P^{-1} x < 0$ holds. However, I am not able to prove this fact. Help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: If what you state is true, then scaling $y$ by a positive scalar $\beta$ should also still give a Hurwitz matrix. From this is can also be noted that this still holds if $\alpha\,\beta>0$, so when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both are negative (so in general they have the same sign).

Comment: Yes. I hope that will work too. But there will be some upper bound on the product $\alpha \beta$

Comment: For the scalar case it indeed does always hold, but I have yet no idea for larger $n$. Maybe a conveniently chosen similarity transformation could help.

Answer (score 0):

Since $P$ is Hurwitz it is invertible. Hence

$$
A \textrm{ is Hurwitz.} \iff \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} I& 0 \\y^TP^{-1} & 1\end{bmatrix}}_{\det(T)\textrm{ is 1}} A = TA = \begin{bmatrix}
P & \alpha x\\
0 & \alpha y^TP^{-1}x 
\end{bmatrix} \textrm{ is Hurwitz.}
$$
since $\alpha>0$ this leads to the condition you have given.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't follow the logic in your answer. Are you finally concluding that $A$ will be Hurwitz for any positive $\alpha$ if $y^\top P^{-1}x<0$ holds?